# How do I blank axis titles in ggplot without affecting the plot size?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to display related ggplots together, with axes all the same size, but with some plots displaying the axis title and other plots blanking the axis title. However, using element_blank() to remove the axis also changes the size of the plot. Here's an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

tb <- tibble(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)

with_x_title <- ggplot(tb, aes(a,b)) +
  geom_point()

without_x_title <- ggplot(tb, aes(a,b)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())

ggdraw() +
  draw_plot(with_x_title, x = 0, y = 0, width = 0.5, height = 1) +
  draw_plot(without_x_title, x = 0.5, y = 0, width = 0.5, height = 1)
```

Here, the y-axis of the plot without an x-axis title is expanded. Is there a way to prevent this happening?

I'm aware I can fudge a fix by changing the height and position in the call to ggdraw, but I'd like a fix that works on the ggplots. I also imagine this is a common problem, but haven't been able to find a solution out there.

Comment: What if rather than `theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())`, you just did `xlab(" ")`. Just set a space as the axis label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the name of the x-axis as empty string, i.e. `""` instead of `element_blank()`

```
...

without_x_title <- ggplot(tb, aes(a,b)) +
  geom_point() +
  # theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = "")

...
```

[image]