# How do I remove tick labels in a ggplot without affecting the plot size?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to display related ggplots together, with axes all the same size, but with some plots displaying the axis tick labels and other plots blanking the axis tick labels. The code below shows two ways I've removed the tick labels, but both resize the plots:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

tb <- tibble(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)

without_x_title <- ggplot(tb, aes(a,b)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "")

without_x_title_labels_1 <- ggplot(tb, aes(a,b)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = "")

without_x_title_labels_2 <- ggplot(tb, aes(a,b)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())

ggdraw() +
  draw_plot(without_x_title, x = 0, y = 0, width = 0.3, height = 1) +
  draw_plot(without_x_title_labels_1, x = 0.3, y = 0, width = 0.3, height = 1) +
  draw_plot(without_x_title_labels_2, x = 0.6, y = 0, width = 0.3, height = 1)
```

Is there a way to prevent this happening?

This is a follow on to a similar question about removing the axis labels asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54678413/how-do-i-blank-axis-titles-in-ggplot-without-affecting-the-plot-size). I'm aware I can fudge a fix by changing the height and position in the call to ggdraw, but I'd like a fix that works on the ggplots. As with the previous question, I imagine this is a common problem, but haven't been able to find a solution out there.

Comment: Oops, misread as "ticks", this will do: `theme(axis.text = element_blank())`

Comment: @Mako212 This removes the text (as in the example) but also causes the plot to resize, which I want to avoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is from @cderv on the [RStudio community site](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-remove-tick-labels-in-a-ggplot-without-affecting-the-plot-size/24071). I'm pasting a slightly edited version here as it complements the two excellent answers above and is perhaps more general.

In the question above, `axis.text.x = element_blank()` will remove the axis text element, so there is a resize.

`scale_x_discrete(labels = "")` is not correct here because the x scale is continuous.

Instead use `scale_x_continuous` to replace labels with "" as in the code below:

```
tb <- tibble(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)

without_x_title <- ggplot(tb, aes(a,b)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "")

# knowing how many break there are
without_x_title_labels_1 <- without_x_title +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = rep("", 5), breaks = 1:5)

# using a function of breaks
without_x_title_labels_2 <- without_x_title +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = function(breaks) {rep_along(breaks, "")})

ggdraw() +
  draw_plot(without_x_title, x = 0, y = 0, width = 0.3, height = 1) +
  draw_plot(without_x_title_labels_1, x = 0.3, y = 0, width = 0.3, height = 1) +
  draw_plot(without_x_title_labels_2, x = 0.6, y = 0, width = 0.3, height = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Matt for coming back to answer - I was having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `plot_grid` function?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

plot_grid(without_x_title, without_x_title_labels_1, without_x_title_labels_2,
          ncol  = 3,
          align = 'hv',
          axis  = 'tb',
          labels = "AUTO")
```

[image]

If you use `patchwork` package and want plot annotation:

```r
library(patchwork)
without_x_title + without_x_title_labels_1 + without_x_title_labels_2 +
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'A',
                  tag_suffix = ')')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Tung. This also works, but neither option gives the granularity of control I'm looking for. So, alternative answers that avoid resizing the ggplots would still be helpful. As a goal, the modified plots should have identical axis positions when viewed in the RStudio plot viewer or when saved as images. I've also tried theme(plot.margin = ...) but this doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [`patchwork` package](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) - available from github

```
# install.packages("devtools")
# devtools::install_github("thomasp85/patchwork")
library(patchwork)
without_x_title + without_x_title_labels_1 + without_x_title_labels_2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @markus, this works, but so far as I can tell patchwork lacks functionality I want to use with ggdraw. For example, with ggdraw I can add and position panel letters to the above plot using '+ draw_plot_label(label = c("A", "B", "C"), size = 15, x = c(0, 0.3, 0.6), y = c(1, 1, 1))'. In patchwork there is 'plot_annotation' but this appears too limited for what I want to do. So, an alternative answer would still be very helpful.